# What is the adjective of the word "pity"?

Tags: word-request

Context:
I feel "pity" for all those poor people.

In dictionary it is written that it is noun.
So if want to convert or I want to say pity so that it looks as an adjective, then how would I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are three ways:

> All those poor people are **pitiful**.
>
> All those poor people are **pitiable**.
>
> All those poor people are **piteous**.

The word **pitiful** can suggest that the speaker feels contempt toward all those poor people—that their poor state is their own fault, the result of low-quality work. **Pitiable** can also suggest contempt, but it's more likely to suggest compassion or resignation about the conditions that led to those people's poverty. **Piteous** indicates that all those poor people merit pity without implying anything about whether anyone actually feels pity toward them.

For more information, see [this article](https://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&pg=PA610&dq=pitiful) in *Merriam-Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms.*

If you're wondering if there is a rule about whether **-ful**, **-able**, and **-ous** carry similar connotations when forming other adjectives: no, there isn't. English has a variety of ways to form adjectives, some from Anglo-Saxon (like **-ful** and **-y**) and some from Latin (like **-able**, **-ous**, **-al**). Adjectives formed by different endings often take on distinct meanings or connotations over the years. There are common patterns, which explain why the above connotations seem natural to a native ear, but they're hard to describe. If there's a rough rule of thumb, it's that words formed from Anglo-Saxon roots tend to be less formal or more suitable for pejorative meanings than comparable words from Latin roots (like **bloody** vs. **sanguinous**, or **mouthy** vs. **oral**), but it's not a rule.